# logout and login in react-native-linkedin npm

Tags: javascript, react-native, npm

I installed react-native-linkedin npm in my app and created application in linkedin developer account.Now I am able to login to my application via linkedin Login ,but I also want to implement linkedin logout.How to achieve it?.Here I am not storing the token locally anywhere.
 My code sample is:

```
      render(){
          return(
         <View>
           <LinkedInModal
            ref={ref => {
              this.modal = ref
            }}
            clientID="xxxxxxxxx"
            clientSecret="xxxxxxxxx"
            redirectUri="xxxxxxxxxx"
            onSuccess={(token) => {
                 console.log("getting token",token);
                  this.getLinkedInUser(token)
                  }}

            onError={(error)=>{
                    console.log("onError",JSON.stringify(error))
                    alert('LinkedIn Login is Cancelled ');
                      }}
            linkText={null}

         />

       <TouchableOpacity style={styles.LinkedInStyle} activeOpacity={0.5} 
          onPress={()=>{
            console.log("linkedin login is  first 
             time",this.state.linkedInFirstTime);
             this.modal.open()
            }
           }> 
       </View>
        ) 
      }
       getLinkedInUser=async ({ access_token })=> {
     try{
       console.log("inside getLinkedInUser",access_token ) ;
        this.setState({ refreshing: true })
        const baseApi = 'https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/'
        const qs = { format: 'json' }
        const params = [
         'first-name',
         'last-name',
         'picture-urls::(original)',
         'headline',
         'email-address',
         'id'
          ]
      fetch(`${baseApi}~:(${params.join(',')})?format=json`, {
      method: 'GET',
        headers: {
         Authorization: 'Bearer ' + access_token,
        },
       })
      .then(async (response)=>response.json())
      .then(async (payload)=>{
       console.log("inside payload");
       this.props.storeData(payload , "linkedin");
       })
    .catch((error)=>{
       console.log("error while fetching",JSON.stringify(error.message));
      })

     }
     catch(error){
       console.log("error",error.message);
      }
     }
```

Comment: You can remove the token which you have received after LogIn

Comment: Can you please suggest the method or  a way to remove token,I couldn't find  anyway to remove it.@IhorSkliar

Comment: @ user10396319, I believe it should be in localStorage or cookies.

Comment: Thnsk you@IhorSkliar.It worked!.

Comment: @user10396319 i used this code for login, but i got always error of propstype. can you help me ?